# Differences between threading and processes?

Tags: process, thread

In an operating systems course (the operating System on which the course is covered is Linux) that I am participating in, we are told that:

1. Processes have priority values which determine what process will be executed.
2. The priority values are determined by a process scheduling algorithm.
3. The threads do not have priority values and they are not scheduled by an algorithm.

On the other hand, I read that each thread has attributes such as: thread priority, identifier, scheduling parameters, and stack size. Besides, there exists a thread scheduling algorithm in multithreading systems.

Which one is true?

Comment: Your question does not seem specific to Unix/Linux. Perhaps a better place to ask would be Stack Overflow?

Comment: "Which one is true?" The difference between processes and threads depends on the implementation of threads on a particular system. What system specifically are you concerned with? Note that different Unices may do things differently too.

Comment: Actually, we are working on Linux-ubuntu

Comment: Ye olde difference between theory and practice.

Comment: Point #3 is not usually part of theory, though.  (-:  Where is this taught?  What textbook?  What course?  I'd like to see what that textbook actually says, rather than this précis, and what operating system it is talking about.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it depends on the definition. Different systems might have different customs, or different names for the same thing.

The [POSIX definition is that a process](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_210) is identified by an address space (memory visible to the process), and that many/most of the OS resources belong to the process. (process ID (obviously), user IDs, working directory, file descriptors...)

On the other hand, [a thread is defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_404) as a "flow of control" within a process, including the runtime environment (CPU registers, floating point status), *and* e.g. the scheduling priority.

So usually: process <-> resources, thread <-> scheduling.

---

But it doesn't have to be exactly that way. In Linux, the resources shared by a process and it's child can be set by the [`clone(2)` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html), so it at least seems possible to have two processes that share file descriptors, but have distinct address spaces. Or the other way around.

Also, in the times of yore, Linux didn't actually have a proper distinction between processes and threads, there were just processes in the kernel level. (Technically the thing we'd usually consider a thread is still called a "process" by the kernel, and a process in the usual sense is called a "process group".)

---

Some sort of threads can be implemented purely in user space, without support from the operating system. In that case, the threads would not be scheduled by the same system as processes, since the OS scheduler would not even know they exist.  But even in this case, the user space implementation would need to have some way of determining which thread to run. (User-space thread implementations are obsolete on systems that implement proper threads, but that's about the only situation I can think of that's even close to your third point.)